# Float64 in golang

Tags: go, floating-point

I am currently doing a simple variance function with float64. However i encountered a problem when dividing the float64 with the NaN result.
In my main I have a simple loop to sum all the data minus the mean. after that i am doing the division by the length of my container. Anyone know what mistake I did?

```
for _, letter := range floatContainer {
    variance += VarSqrt(letter, average)
}
    variance /= float64(len(floatContainer) - 1) <---- Here is the problem

func VarSqrt(n, mean float64) float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(n - mean)
}
```

Comment: Is len(floatContainer) = 1?

Answer (score 0):

to calculate variance, you should sum all the data minus the mean's square, not sqrt, and the length of array should > 1

here is the sample code

```golang
func mean(nums []float64) float64 {
    var s float64 = 0
    for _, x := range nums {
        s += x
    }
    return s / float64(len(nums))
}

func variance(nums []float64) float64 {
    var res float64 = 0
    var m = mean(nums)
    var n = len(nums)

    for _, x := range nums {
        res += (x - m) * (x - m)
    }

    return res / float64(n-1)
}
```